# Imágenes fuera del servidor con Spring MVC y GlassFish Server - Utilizar /*.htm en web.xml

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con Spring en GlassFish Server. Puedo desplegar correctamente todo pero ahora quiero servir imágenes que estén fuera de las carpetas del proyecto para que se mantengan independientes. Estas son subidas por el usuario.

Actualmente puedo acceder por esta url:

```
http://localhost:8080/SistemaCarrduci/imagenes/colores.png
```

Pero tuve que modificar **web.xml** de esta manera:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name> 
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Cuando antes utilizaba esto:

```
<url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
```

Por esta razón ahora los controladores no funcionan y tengo que cambiarlos pero no lo quiero hacer así. ¿Hay alguna manera de configurarlo que siga funcionando como tenía configurado el **web.xml**?

---

## MIS CONFIGURACIONES

Para lograr esto agregue esta línea en el **dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/imagenes/**" location="file:///c:/SERVIDOR/img/"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución era más fácil de lo que pensaba

En mi **web.xml** agregue estas lineas:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servicio/*</url-pattern> <!--ESTA MAPEA LA URL PARA QUE SPRING LA DETECTE-->
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

Después en mi **dispatcher-servlet.xml** defino las rutas por las que accedere a las carpetas de esta manera:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/fichero/**" location="file:///c:/SERVIDOR/ficheros/"/> 
<mvc:resources mapping="/imagenes/**" location="file:///c:/SERVIDOR/img/"/>
```

Y como estoy trabajando con spring  security tambien solo ocupo darle permisos a las correspondientes url.

Para acceder al contenido hago esto:

```
http://localhost:8080/SistemaCarrduci/servicio/fichero/fichero.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring te permite bajo la estructura maven poder colocar en la carpeta

> RESOURCE

un archivo para configuracion, que te permite acceder y colocar un gran numero de parametros externalizando la misma. Este por defecto se llama

> application.properties

Dentro de este archivo plano puedes agregar los parametros que sugieres.
ejm:

```
database.url=jdbc:postgresql:/localhost:5432/instance
database.username=foo
database.password=bar
spring.application.name=cruncher
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
server.port=9000
```

Aqui te dejo un link de todas las configuraciones posibles adicional a las que puedes agregar
[Spring application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)